# Is it possible to convert an empty string ("") to undefined in one line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined, string

Just wondering. I have a method (URItemplate) which I need to return undefined in case variables are not defined. Currently I'm doing this:

```
 var x = UriTemplate.parse(value || "").expand({"some":"properties"} || {});
```

In case `value` and my expand object `{}` are passed as empty string and empty object, x equates to `""`.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do with an empty string to convert it to undefined, so I can later call...

```
 $.ajax({"url": x || default_url})...
```

Of course there is `if-else` or `?:` and my `||` is also an if-else, but I'm wondering if there is another way to do this as a one-liner.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that if `x` is an empty string, it will fallback to `default_url` in your current code. `x` needs to be falsy, not necessarily `undefined` and the empty string (along with `null`, `undefined` and `0`) is falsy.

Comment: Also a good point. Nice!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `||`:

```
x = x || undefined;
```

If "x" has any falsy value (including the empty string), it will end up as `undefined`.

Comment: Ah nice... let me try.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: And I used  (x==undefined?'':x) . || construct looks much beter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a function :

```
// "def" means "default (to undefined)"
function def(v) { if (v) return v; }
x = def(x);
y = def(y);
```

Well, you need at least two lines (cheating a bit) =D